# References to NuGet packages incorrectly changed to local project references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I only discovered this when I had to change my Solution's platform from `x86` to `x64` due to an `x86` app's inability to see `QWinSta.exe` (FWIW `Any CPU` can't see it either). Upon the switch, everything goes haywire and my dozen or so utility libraries and base class projects can't find their references. A quick switch back and a rebuild sets everything right again (but of course doesn't give me the `x64` that I need).

Up until now I've been building everything `x86`, just to be safe. So... apparently it's time to pay the piper.

What's happened is that all of my NuGet package references in these supporting projects have somehow gotten changed to now point to the assembly locations in the projects' bin folders, instead of the package folders where they originally started out.

For example, I have a project called Extensions that provides a collection of handy extension methods that I've built up over time. I use this project in several different solutions. One of its package references that used to be:

```
<SolutionDir>\Packages\Quartz.2.3.1\lib\net40\Quartz.dll
```

is now:

```
<CommonLibrariesDir>\Extensions\bin\x86\Debug\Quartz.dll
```

This is why everything falls apart when I switch to `x64`—the referenced assemblies simply aren't there.

I'd like to better understand the inner workings of Package Manager with regard to this situation, so I can fix it and better structure things to avoid it in the future, but I'm afraid I don't know where to start. I've been wading through documentation not knowing what I'm looking for.

One thing possibly worthy of note: Often when I create a new solution/project and add/reference an existing project that in turn contains NuGet packages, I'm prompted to 'Restore missing packages,' which I go ahead and do. Could this have had something to do with it?

Comment: HI Jeff, Greg from ClickOnceMore here. Apologies to everyone for this unorthodox way to contact Jeff, I picked the quietest question I could fin to do so. Jeff I have replied to all of your emails but the replies are all bouncing back with "TLS Negotiation failed". Do you have an alternative email I could contact you on please? Thanks, Greg

Comment: @GregJackman - Now *that's* customer service! Sure am glad I went with ClickOnceMore :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was quick.

I decided to leave the question and answer it here, in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

All it took was one simple command:

`Update-Package -Reinstall`

All of my supporting project references were set right and I was able to switch to `x64` with no trouble. What a surprise!

I found it here:

http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html

> Reinstall all packages in all projects of the current solution:
>
> ```
> Update-Package -Reinstall
> ```